# Mongoose aggregate between two models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to calculate the average rating of all team members in a team.
I have two Mongoose Models, User and Team, and User has an attribute `team` that is basically the `_id` of the team they're in. Also, user has info about their rating.

What I'd like to do is to calculate the average rating their team for all users. I've tried going through the Mongoose API documentation, but I don't get the expected results.

I'm trying to loop through the teams and calculate the average and then after this is done I'll add it to each user object returning with the callback.

This is what I've tried:

`teams.forEach(function(team) {
        teamLockedMapping[team._id] = team.teamLocked
        const teamMembers = team.members
        User
          .aggregate([
            {$match: {'team': team._id}},
          ])
          .exec(function(err,res) {
            console.log(res)
          })
      })

```
teams.forEach(function(team) {
    User
      .aggregate([
        {$match: {'team': team._id}},
      ])
      .exec(function(err,res) {
        console.log(res)
      })
  })`
```

However, res is just `undefined` and if I log `err` I get:

`MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument`

Comment: What is your mongodb and mongoose version?

Comment: It's 4.1.2, should probably update that.